# How to write string data to file like file.json using typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic2

I have json file data like this:

```
{
  "word": {
    "meanings": "buang",
    "key_word": "throw"
  }
}
```

I need to write this data to a physical file using typescript, example "my_data.json". But somehow, I do not know how to do it.

```
private current_data = '{"word":{"meanings":"buang","key_word":"throw"}}';

//Write new or override exist file my_data.json
...
```

Anyone can help me? I tried to figure out but still not find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your js running? In node or the browser?

Comment: @NitzanTomer browser...I used ionic2

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js